# How to ignore Content Length in Nginx?

Tags: http, nginx

Faced with a problem: if GET request was supplied with non-zero Content-Length property and there is no body, nginx will not proxy this request. Example of how to reproduce it:

`nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)`

```
# conf.d/main.conf

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name  example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5060;
    }
}
```

When listen 5060 port via netcat: `nc -l -p 5060`

After, make CURL request:

```
curl -vvv -X GET   http://example.com/ -H 'Content-Length: 1'
```

This request will be closed after default `proxy_send_timeout` 60s.

As i understand, Nginx see Content-Length and wait body before transmit request to proxy. How to resolve it, without changing the reqest header?

Please note: i tried to do it with Haproxy - it work despite non-zero Content-Length and zero body.